# Prisma Post request Argument is missing in nextjs api route handler

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, prisma, next.js13

I encounter an issue when I send a post request with JSON content to Next.js API route handlers using thunder client

```
{
  "category_name": "Category Name"
}
```

When sending a POST request using Thunder Client or in the frontend, i get 500 Internal Server Error with this code

```
Invalid `prisma.category.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
+   category_name: String
  }
}

Argument `category_name` is missing.
```

i use nextjs api Route Handlers to post Category Name

```
//api/category/route.js
import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request){
    const {category_name} = request.body;
    const userCategory = await prisma.category.create({
        data:{
            category_name: category_name
        }
    })
    const data = await userCategory.json();
    return NextResponse.json(data);
}
```

and here is the prisma schema

```
generator client {
    provider        = "prisma-client-js"
    previewFeatures = ["jsonProtocol"]
}

datasource db {
    provider          = "postgresql"
    url               = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling
    directUrl         = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection
}

model Products {
    id                  Int             @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    product_name        String          @unique @db.VarChar(50)
    product_description String          @db.Text
    quantity            Int             @db.Integer
    price               Decimal         @db.Decimal()
    pproduct            Category        @relation(fields: [category_id], references: [id])
    category_id         Int
    productsOrder_id    Int
    ProductsOrder       ProductsOrder[]
}

model Category {
    id            Int        @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    category_name String     @unique @db.VarChar(50)
    products      Products[]
}

model ProductsOrder {
    id          Int        @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    date        DateTime   @default(now())
    quantity    Int        @db.Integer
    totalAmount Decimal    @db.Decimal()
    products    Products[]
}

model Service {
    id           Int            @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    serviceName  String         @db.VarChar(50)
    price        Decimal        @db.Decimal()
    ServiceOrder ServiceOrder[]
}

model ServiceOrder {
    id          Int       @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("floor(random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000"))
    quantity    Int       @db.Integer
    totalAmount Decimal   @db.Decimal()
    services    Service[]
}
```

The issue I am facing is that I can’t send a post request to the database to save the category name or the product info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what `req.body`

```
(property) Body.body: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null
```

use `req.json` in `try/catch`

```
export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    const { category_name } = await request.json();
    const userCategory = await prisma.category.create({
      data: {
        category_name: category_name,
      },
    });
    const data = await userCategory.json();
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("eror in post", error);
  }
}
```